# Different type showing for Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

When i hardcode a Series to see its type, i see it as below

```
type(qs_raw_document[1])


str
```

But when i put this in a loop, i see the output as

```
n = qs_raw_document.shape[0]
for i in range(0,3):
    text = qs_raw_document[i]
    print(type(qs_raw_document[i]))

<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

The reason i am asking this query is that some of my function expects the input as str only.

I am trying to do some Pre-processing in NLP text.

```
    type(qs_raw_document[1])

    n = qs_raw_document.shape[0]
    for i in range(0,3):
        text = qs_raw_document[i]
        print(type(qs_raw_document[i]))
```

I am expecting both to give the same result

Comment: Your data type is string in both the cases. How is your *Series* look like? I can't reproduce your 1st result!

Comment: Can you do qs_raw_document.apply(type).unique() ?

Comment: Are you using ipython? Is that where you see `str` ?

Comment: I am creating a series by combining 3 columns from a DataFrame. qs_raw_document = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3'].  I need the data to be in a single column for performing some NLP related tasks

Answer (score 0):

`<class 'str'>` is how `str` is printed:

```
In [11]: print(str)
<type 'str'>

In [12]: str(str)
Out[12]: "<type 'str'>"

In [13]: repr(str)
Out[13]: "<type 'str'>"

In [14]: str.__name__
Out[14]: 'str'
```

Note: ipython prints the `__name__` rather than the str/repr.